# Can I see my removed answers if I am under 10K through reputation tab?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

A while ago, I managed to scrape together a decent answer on History SE. The question was kind of controversial and people are touchy about that stuff so the OP flipped out when s/he didn't like the answer which challenged their preformed opinion and in the end, a user and a diamond mod deleted the question (Not my fault, only feedback that I received was positive).

Now I am aware that you can see your upvoted and deleted answers in the reputation tab by checking "Show removed posts" checkmark. I can do that just fine and see it. But I do have privilege of viewing deleted posts on History SE.

So what I am not sure about is, "Could I view that question through reputation tab if I didn't have the reputation to view deleted posts?" given that it was my own answer.

To make it clear, consider the following scenario:

1. There is an answer from User X.
2. The answer gets a number of Upvotes
3. For a certain reason, the question is deleted either by the asker or by a mod or by user-deletion votes
4. User X doesn't have privilege to view deleted posts.

In this scenario, Can user X find their deleted answer through reputation tab as there ought to be a negative entry there e.g. -40.

Comment: @rene Thanks. [I know that's how it works for searching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/307083) but is it the same for Reputation tab method as well?

Comment: Even without reputation to view deleted posts in general, user can always view their own deleted answer,  even if the question itself is deleted, even with 1 rep. They will see the deleted question and their own deleted answers, without seeing other deleted answers on the question. I just confirmed that on Movies.SE where I have low rep, and kept a link to a question which got deleted after I answered it. But it's not linked from the profile.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes that is correct, keeping a link will always allow you to view your deleted post. In most cases, like the one I mentioned where unbeknownst to me the question was deleted, users don't have a link. So the only way to see the post is either do the search with isDeleted flag or see the reputation tab (Both of which require 10k).

Comment: As @rene said before, you have the "deleted recent answers" and "deleted recent questions" in the answers/questions tab of your profile, available for 60 days since the deletion.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ah yes! Forgot about that :D. Rene mentioned it in the first comment here, which has apparently been deleted now.

Comment: True, rene don't like to keep comments around for some reason.

Comment: *waits for rene to respond with* no comment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's an example from my EL&U account (where I have less than 10k); it shows an answer has been deleted but it's not a link, so I can't access it.

[image]

**But**, as suggested by @gnat in the comments, the record for the positive events *does* have a link:

[image]

<sub>(it's hard to see the difference; you have to trust me on my word)</sub>

The only downside to this is that the negative record is probably easier to find.

---

For comparison, on Stack Overflow (where I have more than 10k), there *is* a link on the negative events:

[image]

Comment: That's great :O! Thanks Gnat and Glorfindel. Which raises the question, If <10k users access their own upvoted and deleted answers this way, why put the 60 days limit or 10k restriction? Just let them see it via search too like others can, just don't make deleted answers of others visible.

Comment: I suspect the link for upvoted posts is a bug. (one of those "nice to have" bugs.)

Comment: maybe words negative/positive would better be changed to removed/added. Because if the post has only votes down then it will be opposite: their adding will show negative and deletion positive rep changes :) @NSNoob see [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/165773) ([meta-tag:status-declined-for-no-good-reason])

Comment: @gnat well, in the downvote case, the reputation is still removed in the 'forward' event. IMHO it better to stick with this terminology for now; the question specifically mentions upvotes and that is by far the most common scenario.